# PHP Variable as a parameter in the URL

Tags: php, url, parameters

I want to create weather informer that shows weather forecast by visitor's IP.

I'm trying to place variable `$ip` to the URL but it doesn't work. When I place real IP instead of `.$ip.` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=.$ip.&localObsTime&num_of_days=5&format=json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$outputJson = curl_exec($ch);
 if ($outputJson === FALSE) {
 echo 'Error: '.curl_error($ch);
 }

 echo '<pre> ';
 print_r($outputJson);   
 echo '</pre> ';
```

Comment: when you do print_r do you have the correct output at least ?

Comment: @Tarek Yes, It returns json data (if IP is real, not a variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got some unnecessary dots before and after `$ip`:

Use any of following:

```
"http://...$ip..."
"http://...{$ip}..."
"http://..." . $ip . "...";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=".$ip."&localObsTime&num_of_days=5&format=json");
```

Comment: because of the double quotes that has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to concatenate the string since you're using doublequotes. so you either do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=$ip&localObsTime&num_of_days=5&format=json");
```

in the url.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the string concatenation operator inside the string. either use

```
"http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=$ip&localObsTime&num_of_days=5&format=json"
```

or

```
'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q='.$ip.'&localObsTime&num_of_days=5&format=json'
```